# VS2012 Code Analysis Warning C6011 not showing all potential dereferencing of null pointers

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I'm working on a C program in Visual Studio. Recently, I turned on Code Analysis (All rules) and after some testing I realized that the warning C6011 (dereferencing of null pointer) is not working as I expected.

The following code returns a warning C6011

```
struct test_struct
{
    unsigned int    int_test;
};

void set_to_1000(struct test_struct* const test)
{
    if (test == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    test->int_test = 1000;
}
```

However, the following code does not return such a warning (same struct as above)

```
void set_to_1000(struct test_struct* const test)
{    
    test->int_test = 1000;
}
```

Throughout the program, NULL is in general an acceptable input parameter. Is there any setting I can turn on so that the second example also returns a warning C6011?

Comment: Sounds like a tool bug more than anything else. Also note that `* const` is clutter when it comes to function parameters, since the function parameter is a local copy anyway. Who cares if the function changes the local copy of the pointer.

Comment: @Danh: that would be the correct behavior, of course. But if I return, I don't get the warning I want to show in this example.

Comment: @frangge to me, it's perfect normal to pass a never-null pointer to a function